# Adding a class to an image using preprocess function

Tags: theming, hooks

I am having trouble adding a class to an image using a preprocessor function in Drupal 9. Specifically, I only want certain images to have that class added. The image is being added using paragraphs.

I've tried a few variations of the following and cannot seem to get class added. I've also tried using `['#item']` but it causes an error.

```
function confluence_preprocess_field__paragraph__field_card_image(&$variables) {    
    foreach($variables['items'] as $key => $item){
        $variables['items'][ $key ]['content']['item']['class'] = 'card-img-top';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it via the content's `#item_attributes` array like so:

```
foreach($variables['items'] as $key => $item){
  $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#item_attributes']['class'][] = 'card-img-top';
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works. Thank you so much.